# NSMutableString append data error

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have AsyncSocket like this.

```
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {
NSString *message = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
[data getBytes:&tdata];
  if (tdata > 5) {

    if(bheader){
        if(!charS){
            if([message isEqualToString:@"S"]){
                CMSG = message;
                charS=YES;
            }
        }
        else{
            NSMutableString *tmp = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
            [tmp appendString:CMSG];       <<<<< This is code error at loop 2, 
            [tmp appendString:message];     the first loop success but second is fail
            CMSG = tmp;
            [tmp release];
        }
    }
    else{  
        if (message){            
            cmessage = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%@",cmessage,message]  ;
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Error converting received data into UTF-8 String");

        cdata++;
        if(cdata==idata) {
            msgComplete=YES;
        }

    }

    if (msgComplete) {
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:cmessage forKey:kNotificationMessage];
        [notificationCenter postNotificationName:kNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
        cmessage=@"";
        CMSG=@"";
        msgComplete=NO;
        bheader=YES;
        cdata=0;
        charS=NO;
        [cmessage release];

    }
}

[sock readDataToLength:1 withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
```

}

This code fail at second loop at `[tmp appendString:CMSG];` Thread 1: Program received signal "SIGABRT"
How fix this error ?
Thanks gurus,

Comment: You say "loop", but there are no loops in this code. Is it running inside a loop?

Comment: if you're running this in the debugger SIGABRT typically comes with an exception and stack trace.   _*Too*_ much trouble to include those?

Answer (score 0):

CMSG is assigned to tmp but tmp is released right afterwards. CMSG needs to be retained throughout the loop.

```
CMSG = tmp;   //<< should be CMSG = [tmp retain];
[tmp release];
```

Now you have another potential problem. You are using a deprecated method here

```
[data getBytes:&tdata];
  if (tdata > 5) {
```

[getBytes:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/getBytes%3alength%3a) was deprecated because of a potential buffer overrun and the result of getBytes is not appropriate to use for `if(tdata > 5)`. If you want to check the length of bytes get that that from the [`NSData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#) object.

Comment: Wow, this is work thanks Joe, i'm new on Object-C, i'm not realy sure about [tmp retai], when i must use this ? due on other case i use this (CMSG = tmp )code but work it :).

Comment: The Memory Management Programming Guide is very insightful to the uses of release and retain. When you assigned tmp to CMSG CMSG was just a reference to tmp and then you released tmp. At that point tmp was useless therefore making CMSG useless and then you attempted to use it in the 2nd loop. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: thanks joe, but why i use this code have error : `NSMutableString *tmp = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:CMSG];

                [tmp appendString:message];
                CMSG = [tmp retain];
                [tmp release];`

Comment: Is CMSG nil the first time you use and is it defined as NSString? If CMSG is nil or not a string that method will raise an exception.

Comment: hi joe you have opened my mind, CMSG on above code initial from `if([message isEqualToString:@"S"]){
                    CMSG = message;
                    charS=YES;
                }` but after i change CMSG = message with CMSG = [message retain] this code is work. thanks very much joe.

Comment: Your welcome make sure you read through the Memory Management Guide I linked you above. That way you get a complete understanding of when and why to use alloc/init, copy, retain, release, and autorelease.

Answer (score 0):

I see an error that may or may not be the ultimate problem here. In the final conditional statement, you have:

```
cmessage=@"";
...
[cmessage release];
```

I don't think you should be releasing that string. I don't actually know all of the ins and outs of `NSString` objects that are defined in that way (as opposed to `stringWithFormat:` or `initWithString:`), but I don't think that you have ownership of that string object. You shouldn't have to release it.

Remove that `release` message and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi Charlie thanks for reply, error not on cmessage, but CMSG, i have try to remark [cmessage release] but still same error, any other suggestion ?

Comment: Did you retain CMSG as Joe suggested? Where is the loop here?

Comment: Releasing the string literal @"" is not a problem other than being bad practice since it never gets deallocated. The real problem is it looks like user\d+ is trying to release objects by setting them to an empty string. **DO NOT** set cmessage or CMSG or any other string to @"" in an attempt to release as it will cause a memory leak. Call [cmessage release] , [CMSG release] only.

Comment: :) sorry charlie, i not read Joe command before, thanks for your response.

Comment: @joe, thanks for your suggestion, i'll remember that, i'm still confused when must use [cmessage release], this use after we use [cmessage alloc]? make memory leak? if on loop i use ex : cmessage = [[NSString alloc] initwitthformat:@"test %@",anymessage]  and i release on dealoc method or end of loop ?

Comment: Joe could you give me simple explain about alloc release retain copy :)